# ETF of 2000 or more stocks but excludes stocks from the S&P 500?

Tags: etf, index-fund, market-indexes

I believe the S&P 500 is overvalued and small-cap stocks are less overvalued. So I would like to buy market index (like 2000 or 5000 companies) but without the S&P 500 companies.

Are there such ETFs?

- For the US
- And similar ETFs (small companies excluding large companies) for the whole world or Europe/Asia.

P.S.

Ideally 2000 companies should be **weighted equally** (same cash value in ETF for each stock), not proportional to its market cap.

And would be nice to being able to **trade options** on such ETF.

Comment: Well, the Russell 2000 is capitalization weighted. A capitalization weighted index is a momentum fund and not really diversified. The smaller companies in the index just wait in the wings for bigger position in the index.

Comment: Questions seeking product/service recommendations are specifically off-topic. Sorry.

Comment: I voted to close, but FWIW, you won't find exactly what you're looking for. I'd check out the list at https://www.etf.com/channels/equal-weighted-etfs and https://www.invesco.com/us/financial-products/etfs/strategies/equal-weight-investing?audienceType=investor#tab_tab3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ideally 2000 companies should be **weighted equally** (same cash value in ETF for each stock), not proportional to its market cap.

Equal-weighted ETFs with 2000 companies and no S&P 500 components used to exist in the US. The Guggenheim Russell 2000 Equal Weight ETF (NYSE Arca: EWRS) changed to track another index in 2016, becoming EWSC (see below), so it is gone now. The Invesco Russell 2000 Equal Weight ETF (NYSE Arca: EQWS) fit all your requirements. Unfortunately, such ETFs are not popular, and Invesco liquidated the ETF in 2019.

As far as I can see, there are no US ETFs that fit all your requirements at the moment.

The closest I can find are:

- Invesco S&P MidCap 400 Equal Weight ETF (NYSE Arca: EWMC)
- Invesco S&P SmallCap 600 Equal Weight ETF (NYSE Arca: EWSC)

But these have less than 2000 companies, and do not have options.

There aren't that many equal-weighted ETFs in the first place. Within the small number of equal-weighted ETFs, most of them have large-caps in them. So a requirement to exclude S&P 500 companies leaves zero or nearly zero ETFs to choose from. Add your options trading requirement… you will have no ETFs left.

The equal-weighted Russell 2000 ETFs had small AUMs. Their liquidation and transformation over the past few years is a sign that they are not commercially viable.

Answer (score 1):

The Russell 2000 has little to no overlap with the S&P 500, and has a market-cap-weighted ETF with options (IWM), but (as noted by Flux) no longer has an equal-weighted ETF.

If you relax the requirement of 2000 or more stocks, the S&P MidCap 400 and S&P SmallCap 600 have equal-weighted ETFs (EWMC and EWSC), but they do not appear to have options.

Realistically, since the S&P MidCap 400 and S&P SmallCap 600 each have a relatively narrow range of market caps, similar performance is likely for their market-cap-weighted ETFs (IJH and IJR), which do have options.